# Recycler only load for the first time if I intent to the second activity or switch the app the recylerview doesn't load items

Tags: android, firebase

When I intent to the other activity and press the back button the recycler view doesn't load the items. Or if I switch the app still the recycler view doesn't loads items. I tried changing the width and height to `wrap_content` and `match_parent` nothing works.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">  

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_below="@+id/searchitembar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/recycler_products" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

I have used recycler view inside expandable layout
Customize Adapter

```
        viewHolder.expandableLayout.setInRecyclerView(false);
        viewHolder.expandableLayout.setExpanded(expandState.get(position));
        viewHolder.expandableLayout.setListener(new ExpandableLayoutListenerAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void onPreOpen() {
                changeRotate(viewHolder.button,0f,180f).start();
                expandState.put(position,true);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPreClose() {
                changeRotate(viewHolder.button,180f,0f).start();
                expandState.put(position,false);
            }

        });
        viewHolder.button.setRotation(expandState.get(position)?180f:0f);
        viewHolder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                viewHolder.expandableLayout.toggle();
            }
        });


        ((ProductWithCategoryViewHolder) holder).product.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager= new LinearLayoutManager(context);
        ((ProductWithCategoryViewHolder) holder).product.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        productAdapter= new ProductAdapter(tempproductlist,context,shop_id);

        ((ProductWithCategoryViewHolder) holder).product.setAdapter(productAdapter);
```

Comment: please add some code to get the whole picture

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can help you exactly. Thank you

Comment: edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you switch Activity

```
val intent = Intent(Context,SecondActivityName::class.java)
startActivityForResult(mIntent,requestCode)
```

You need to use `startActivityForResult(mIntent, requestCode)` for open Second Activity where `requestCode` is some random integer.

After while switch back to first activity 
Callback received on below method

```
    override onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?{
          if(requestCode = your provided integer){
              //You update your recyclerview adapter here
              RecyclerView.Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
          }
    }
```

If you switch app and while come back refresh recyclerview

```
override onRestart(){
      //You update your recyclerview adapter here
      RecyclerView.Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
}
```